# Combine 2 csv file using python with the specified amount

Tags: python, csv, combiners

I want to combine 2 file CSV data, but not all data.
e.g:
a.csv + b.csv, where b.csv have 20 data. But I want to take only 10 data from that, and then take 11-20 data. Or the first 10 and the second 10

Then insert the first 10 data into a.csv, and the second 10 data into a.csv too
My Question is how can I take only specific total data?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('testNegatif.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('trainNegatif.csv', nrows=10)

output=df1.append(df2)
output.to_csv("output.csv", sep=',')
```

I expect the result return that I want, but the actual result is combining all data.

Comment: You want to add ten rows of b.csv to a.csv? Which ten - the first ten, every other row?

Comment: yes, can be random or the first ten hehe

Comment: See the option `nrows` in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you can use `nrows`

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('testNegatif.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('trainNegatif.csv', nrows=10)

output=df1.append(df2)
output.to_csv("output.csv", sep=',')
```

See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html for more options

Comment: btw, how about nrows for specific range of rows?

Comment: @TryaSoviKartikasari Look at `skiprows` and `skipfooter` in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Without using Pandas. Read the lines of each file; add ten lines from one file's data to the other; write the result to another file.

```
with open('a.csv') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
with open('b.csv') as f:
    bdata = f.readlines()

data.extend(bdata[:10])

with open('output.csv', 'w'):
    f.writelines(data)
```

If the files are HUGE and you don't want to read the entire contents into memory, use some itertools functions.

```
import itertools
with open('a.csv') as a, open('b.csv') as b, open('output.csv', 'w') as out:
    first_ten = itertools.islice(b, 10)
    for line in itertools.chain(a, first_ten):
        out.write(line)
```

---

Assumes both files have the same number of columns.

Comment: i already tried the code with pandas, # output=df1.append(df2[:200]) , but still not work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Creating two dataframes with data that overlap, so we don't want all of the 'b' data.
# We want to strip off '3,4,5' as they exist in 'a' as well
# ----------Creating the data frames----------
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

dfa = pd.DataFrame(a)
dfa.to_csv('one.csv', index=False)

dfb = pd.DataFrame(b)
dfb.to_csv('two.csv', index = False)
# ---------------------------------------------

# --------Reading through the dataframes-------
one = pd.read_csv('one.csv')
two = pd.read_csv('two.csv')
# ---------------------------------------------

# Stripping off the first 3 data of 'two' the list
output = one.append(two[3:])
output.to_csv("output.csv", sep=',', index=False)
# ---------------------------------------------
```

I hope this answers your question. The important part for you is `output = one.append(two[3:])`. There are more sophisticated ways to do the same thing but this is the simplest.

Comment: i got an error ITypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'